# How to validate number of images in multiple upload in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, file

This is my state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pictures: [] };
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
  }
```

This is my images number validate function

```
validate = () => {
    const pictures = [...this.state.pictures];
    if (pictures.length >= 4) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

This my photo upload handler

```
photosUploadHandler = async () => {
    const uploadedPhotos = this.state.pictures;
    const photoData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < uploadedPhotos.length; i++) {
      photoData.append("image", uploadedPhotos[i]);
    }
    const hotelSlug = this.props.match.params.slug;
    const { data: hotel } = await getHotel(hotelSlug);
    photoData.append("hotel", hotel.id);
    try {
      await uploadPhotos(photoData);
      toast.success("Successfully uploaded");
      this.props.history.replace(`/dashboard/hotels/gallery/${hotelSlug}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

```
<button
    className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
    onClick={() => this.photosUploadHandler()}
    disabled={this.validate}
       >
```

I want the submit button to be disabled whenever a user has upload less than 4 images. The current validate function is not working. What could be wrong. Kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see is you're passing `disabled` a function reference, not calling the function. Call it like this: `disabled={this.validate()}`.

Also, creating a new `pictures` array just to check the length is completely useless. Checking the length does not mutate. Just check it directly

```js
if (this.state.pictures.length >= 4) {
  ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The submit button is still enabled irregardless of the upload status

Comment: Your logic seems backwards. You want the button to be disabled if `this.state.pictures` is less than 4 right? If so, you need to reverse the true and false in `validate`.